# Xamarin Android - Type or namespace "Context" could not be found

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm following [this](https://elearning.xamarin.com/forms/xam110/pcls/exercise2/6-create-abstraction) Xamarin tutorial. Visual Studio throws an error when I use the "Context" class in my Android project. Shouldn't this class be included in my Android app by default?

Also, I defined an interface named "IStreamLoader" in a Portable Class Library called "Portable", and added a reference to "Portable" in my Android project. But referencing "IStreamLoader" in my Android project throws another error.

Are these two errors related?

**Errors**

```
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IStreamLoader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Context' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Context' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**MyTunes.Droid\MainActivity.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;

namespace MyTunes
{
    [Activity(Label = "My Tunes", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : ListActivity
    {
        protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            var data = await SongLoader.Load();

            ListAdapter = new ListAdapter<Song>() {
                DataSource = data.ToList(),
                TextProc = s => s.Name,
                DetailTextProc = s => s.Artist + " - " + s.Album
            };
        }
    }

    public class StreamLoader : IStreamLoader
    {
        private readonly Context context;

        public StreamLoader(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public Stream GetStreamForFilename(string filename)
        {
            return context.Assets.Open(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

**Portable\IStreamLoader.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Portable
{
    public interface IStreamLoader
    {
        System.IO.Stream GetStreamForFilename(string filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
using Android.Content;
```

Comment: Wow yeah that fixed the "Context" errors, thanks! Do you know why my "IStreamLoader" reference might be failing?

Comment: Try using Portable, or public class StreamLoader : Portable.IStreamLoader

Comment: Huh, apparently the Portable\IStreamLoader.cs namespace had to be set to the solution name, not the project name. Although your above solution works too.